# org.springeframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException in jBoss 7.1.1

Tags: spring, web-services, jboss, client, spring-ws

I'm creating a Spring webapplication (actually a portlet for Liferay), where I have to communicate with a webservice. Our webapplication runs on JBoss 7.1.1. I've done this before without much trouble, the only difference was that in that time the application ran on a Tomcat server.

I've tested the webservice with a soap plugin, and I can conclude that the webservice is running ok.

What did I do:

I created pojo files (DTO's?) from the provided .wsdl file, using maven-jaxb2-plugin. Those classes are generated well. Then I've defined my marshalling beans:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {


   @Bean
   public Jaxb2Marshaller persoonServiceMarshaller() {
       Jaxb2Marshaller m = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
       m.setMtomEnabled(true);
       m.setContextPath("services");
       return m;
   }

   @Bean
   public WebServiceTemplate persoonTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller persoonServiceMarshaller) {
       WebServiceTemplate w = new WebServiceTemplate();
       w.setMarshaller(persoonServiceMarshaller);
       w.setUnmarshaller(persoonServiceMarshaller);

       w.setDefaultUri("my hardcoded webservice location URI...");
       return w;
   }
```

Then I wrote a method to test this thing out:

```
@Autowired
    WebServiceTemplate persoonTemplate;

    public int getPersonCount(String lastName, String firstName, int birthYear,
            int birthMonth, String postalCode) {
        System.out.println("Getting PersonCount");

        ZoekPersonen zp = new ObjectFactory().createZoekPersonen();
        PersoonZoekCriteria criteria = new ObjectFactory()
                .createPersoonZoekCriteria();
        if (lastName != null && !lastName.equals("")) {
            criteria.setNaam(new ObjectFactory().createPersoonDTONaam(lastName));
        }
        if (firstName != null && !firstName.equals("")) {
            criteria.setVoornaam(new ObjectFactory()
                    .createPersoonDTONaam(firstName));
        }
        if (birthYear != 0) {
            criteria.setGeboorteJaar(new ObjectFactory()
                    .createPersoonZoekCriteriaGeboorteJaar(birthYear));

        }
        if(birthYear != 0) {
            criteria.setGeboorteMaand(new ObjectFactory()
            .createPersoonZoekCriteriaGeboorteMaand(birthMonth));

        }
        if(postalCode != null && !postalCode.equals("")) {
            criteria.setPostCode(new ObjectFactory()
            .createPersoonZoekCriteriaPostCode(postalCode));
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        JAXBElement<ZoekPersonenResponse> jaxBResponse = (JAXBElement<ZoekPersonenResponse>) persoonTemplate
                .marshalSendAndReceive(new ObjectFactory()
                        .createZoekPersonen(zp));

        return jaxBResponse.getValue().getReturn().getGevondenPersonen()
                .getValue().getPersoonDTO().size();
    }
```

When I test this method, this Exception is thrown:

```
13:12:54,278 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6) 13:12:54,275 ERROR [http--0.0.0.0-443-6][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
13:12:54,279 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6) org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Fault occurred while processing.
13:12:54,281 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at BLL.PersoonBLL.getPersonCount(PersoonBLL.java:53)
13:12:54,283 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at controllers.MyController.renderView(MyController.java:44)
13:12:54,284 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
13:12:54,285 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
13:12:54,286 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
13:12:54,290 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
13:12:54,294 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-6)   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
```

I'm clueless, I think It has something to do with JBoss, googled it, but did not find useful information.

FYI: My dependencies and Plugin from my Maven POM:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src\main\resources</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>PersoonWebService.wsdl</include>
            </schemaIncludes>
            <generatePackage>services</generatePackage>
            <generateDirectory>src\main\java</generateDirectory>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring WS version = 2.1.4-RELEASE
Spring suite version = 3.2.4-RELEASE

Upgrading spring versions or JBoss version is sadly no option. This has to run in an existing production environment.

Hints and tips are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this one on my own:

SoapFaultClientException: Exception is thrown by WebService! My request lacked some parameters that where obligated. Even altough the wsdl did not mention them as required.

==> The problem was not JBoss specific, what I first thought. (Sorry for shaming you Jboss, but I still do not like you ;-) ).

Comment: because you still don't like JBoss :D